# The HDD is encrypted and I did not do this

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, encryption

In the beginning, my laptop has 2 hard disks, the first of the NVME SSD class and the other for HDD storage
My problem, very briefly, is that I was using Windows and then I used the Hackintosh on the Dell laptop, and now I use Ubuntu version 22.04.2 LTS, and when I open the other HDD, I find this message

Failed to Mount 1.0 TB Encrypted
Error Unlocking /dev/sda1:failed to active device: Operation not Supported

I also attached a picture to you to be very clear to you

[Error-Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPm3n.png)

Comment: Both Windows and MacOS encrypt drives during installation. Neither type od encryption is supported by Ubuntu as far as I know.

Comment: Ubuntu also supports multiple encryption methods, and you've provided no details of how that encryption was done, so ask the owner/operator of the machine for details.

Comment: I'm Owner The Machine